# why after disable Javascript in nextjs application nothing renders on the screen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I was reading about Pre-rendering on next.js website. There was an example in which they were saying that if we disable javascript in browser then also we will see static HTML that is pre-rendered by Next. But when I tried with the given example project given on next's website, the UI got blank after disable the javascript.

Link of the article:
https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/data-fetching/pre-rendering

This is the app url give in the above article https://next-learn-starter.vercel.app/

It was written that if you try it on localhost, then also it should render static HTML but on local also it is not the case.

Please can someone explain me why it is happening or something is wrong in the article.

Comment: When I open https://next-learn-starter.vercel.app/ it works with javascript disabled, in Chrome and Firefox. Can you provide more detailed steps to reproduce this ?

Comment: Hey, I dont know why, on my MAC it is working,  but on my another Windows laptop it is not working.

Comment: Which browser (incl version) are you using ? Which windows version ?

Comment: Chrome - Version 109.0.5414.87 (Official Build) (x86_64)
MacOS - MacOS Monterey v12.6.3

Comment: That's the one that's working, right ? I meant you should add details about the setup that is _not_ working.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing but only intermittently and i'm not sure why.  Also, if you look at page source, the statically rendered HTML is there - just not rendering in chrome (mac)

Comment: @Karim You see that happen with https://next-learn-starter.vercel.app ? Or with some other website ?